# Could not find main class:program will exist (Exception in main() thread NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java

```
import java.security.*;
import java.math.*;

public class MD5 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        String s="Anand";
        MessageDigest m=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        m.update(s.getBytes(),0,s.length());
        System.out.println("MD5: "+new BigInteger(1,m.digest()).toString(16));
    }
}
```

In this code everything is fine plus it was working before but now wen i'm running the above code the mentioned exception occurs...
Adding i installed jdk a few seconds ago..
All done with Path JAVA_HOME..
still an exception..
Help...!!!!!

`JAVA_HOME=`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\ where java is installed..

`PATH=`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;

`CLASSPATH=`%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;

compiling command:

```
javac MD5.java
```

running command:

```
java MD5
```

Comment: Did you rename your class after running it once without refactoring? Perhaps your Eclipse run configuration still points to the old class?

Comment: Tell us how you run the class. We can't read your screen.

Comment: it program is running

Comment: No after the re-installation of java i saved the code with a new file name..

Comment: @JB Nizet I wrote the Code Saved it with MD5.java compiled it plotting to the directory to which the code belongs.. Successfully Complied.. compiled with javac But while running code throws an exception.. the same code is running in my other PC

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. Where is the .class file. From where do you run the command? Which command?

Comment: @JBNizet Sir D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin is the location where the file resides im not using any IDE.. I'm compiling the code on command promt pointing to the address above.. After compilation the .class file is been made here...

Comment: @user3455791 add the javac & java command how you executing to your question? also add your PATH environment variable value.

Comment: OK. Fill the following form: the MD5.class file is in the directory _______. I execute the command to run my class from the directory _____________. The command I type to execute it is __________________.

Comment: @Rembo JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\ where java is installed.. PATH =C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;

Comment: @user3455791 and CLASSPATH value? how you executing MD5 java class?

Comment: @JBNizet the MD5.class is in D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin.. i compiled it as javac MD5.java !!! Compiled Succesfully java MD5 for executing

Comment: @Rembo CLASSPATH=%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;   using javac MD5.java to compile and java MD5 to execute

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell java where it can find the classes (or rather, the roots of the package trees). Sinc eyour class is in the default package, and located in the directory from where you run the java command, you just need

```
java -classpath . MD5
```

or

```
java -cp . MD5
```

You should never rely on a global CLASSPATH environment variable. Doing that is a nightmare as soon as you have two different Java apps. And the JDK bin folder has nothing to do in the classpath.

Note that using the default package is a very bad practice, and that you should never put your own files in the directory where Java is installed.

Comment: Sir the problem is i installed jdk to C drive then i copied the entire java folder to my D drive to avoid using default directory i.e C: Now i cant understand im using  D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin path to find my compiled class file now when the classpath will try locating the class file it will obviously try finding it in C drive so which classpath should i give C drives or D drives????

Comment: @user3455791 that is not the correct way, uninstall JDK and re-install it in another location, where you like. and set the same path in `JAVA_HOME` , `PATH`.

Comment: The classpath doersn't have anything to do with where Java is installed. It contains the location where to find the classes. Re-read my answer, because I think you missed everything of what I've said.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank You Sir.. Problem Solved..  Dot(.) made the difference.. Thank You Everyone for your cooperation and concern about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.` to your `CLASSPATH` environment value, that tells jvm to look current directory for the class.

like:

```
CLASSPATH=%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;.;
```

or else follow @JB Nizet answer